# adding columns from one file after a column in a second file while considering the two files have different number of columns

Tags: unix, awk, paste, cut

File 1

```
001 00A 892 J27
002 00G 742 M65
003 00B 934 B32
004 00J 876 K57
005 00k 543 N21
```

File 2 has 1,628,433 columns but, would like to add all four columns from file 1 after column one in this file.

```
a 2 T ..........
b 3 C ..........
c 4 G ..........
d 5 A ..........
e 6 B ..........
```

Desired output

```
a 001 00A 892 J27 2 T ..........
b 002 00G 742 M65 3 C ..........
c 003 00B 934 B32 4 G ..........
d 004 00J 876 K57 5 A ..........
e 005 00k 543 N21 6 B ..........
```

Tried the following

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1,$2,$3,$4} {print $1,a[FNR],$5}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Is the first output line supposed to be `a 001 00A 892 J27` or `a 001 00A 892 J27 2 T ....`

Comment: This works but the output file is not tab delimited as files 1 &2 are

Comment: That's a surprising comment: there's nowhere in your question where you say "tab delimited".

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry I missed your first question. The first output is supposed to be the second ouput option you presented in your first question  'a 001 00A 892 J27 2 T ....'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{getline f1 < "file1"; $1 = $1 OFS f1; print}' file2
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[FNR]=$1;next} {$1=$1 OFS arr[FNR]} 1' file2 file1
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `FNR==NR` condition when file2 is being read. Create array with index of line number and have 1st field as its value in it. While reading file1 save value of equivalent array of current line into first field then print current line there.

Answer (score 3):

This version is lighter on memory:
it only reads one line at a time from each file:

```sh
awk '{getline f1 < "file1"; $1 = $1 OFS f1; print}' file2
```

Comment: This is almost correct but, both input files are tab delimited  and the desired output file is tab delimited  as well.  Sorry I forgot to mention it my question.  I tried using your command but adding in the tab delimited but it still is not working awk '{getline f1 < "file1"; $1 = $1 OFS="/t" f1; print}' file2

Comment: use `awk -v OFS='\t' '...`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 file2) file1 <(cut -d' ' -f2- file2)
a 001 00A 892 J27 2 T ..........
b 002 00G 742 M65 3 C ..........
c 003 00B 934 B32 4 G ..........
d 004 00J 876 K57 5 A ..........
e 005 00k 543 N21 6 B ..........
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python that deals with the input files one line at a time:

```
python3 -c '
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1, open(sys.argv[2]) as f2:
    for l1, l2 in zip(f1,f2):
        lf1,lf2=map(str.split, [l1,l2])
        print(" ".join([lf2[0]]+lf1+lf2[1:]))
' file1 file2
```